# Cant ssh into server even though security group allows it

Tags: ssh, terraform

I have the following script:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "xxx"
  secret_key = "xxx"
  region     = "sa-east-1"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
    tags {
        Name = "igw"
    }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"

  tags {
    Name = "Main"
  }

  depends_on = [
        "aws_internet_gateway.igw"
    ]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ssh" {
  name        = "ssh"
  description = "(Proxy) Allow SSH"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "proxy" {
  ami             = "ami-286f2a44"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  key_name        = "spkeypar"
  subnet_id       = "${aws_subnet.main.id}"
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.ssh.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address  = false
}

resource "aws_eip" "pib" {
  instance = "${aws_instance.proxy.id}"
  vpc      = true
}

output "ip" {
  value = "${aws_eip.pib.public_ip}"
}
```

when it finishes, I can see all was created, I can the security group with port 22 open and correctly attached to the instance, but I cannot ssh into it at all. I'm using the public ip from Elastic Ip.

This is the output of `terraform plan`:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + aws_eip.pib
      id:                                    <computed>
      allocation_id:                         <computed>
      association_id:                        <computed>
      domain:                                <computed>
      instance:                              "${aws_instance.proxy.id}"
      network_interface:                     <computed>
      private_ip:                            <computed>
      public_ip:                             <computed>
      vpc:                                   "true"

  + aws_instance.proxy
      id:                                    <computed>
      ami:                                   "ami-286f2a44"
      associate_public_ip_address:           "false"
      availability_zone:                     <computed>
      ebs_block_device.#:                    <computed>
      ephemeral_block_device.#:              <computed>
      instance_state:                        <computed>
      instance_type:                         "t2.micro"
      ipv6_address_count:                    <computed>
      ipv6_addresses.#:                      <computed>
      key_name:                              "spkeypar"
      network_interface.#:                   <computed>
      network_interface_id:                  <computed>
      placement_group:                       <computed>
      primary_network_interface_id:          <computed>
      private_dns:                           <computed>
      private_ip:                            <computed>
      public_dns:                            <computed>
      public_ip:                             <computed>
      root_block_device.#:                   <computed>
      security_groups.#:                     <computed>
      source_dest_check:                     "true"
      subnet_id:                             "${aws_subnet.main.id}"
      tenancy:                               <computed>
      volume_tags.%:                         <computed>
      vpc_security_group_ids.#:              <computed>

  + aws_internet_gateway.igw
      id:                                    <computed>
      tags.%:                                "1"
      tags.Name:                             "igw"
      vpc_id:                                "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  + aws_security_group.ssh
      id:                                    <computed>
      description:                           "(Proxy) Allow SSH"
      egress.#:                              "1"
      egress.482069346.cidr_blocks.#:        "1"
      egress.482069346.cidr_blocks.0:        "0.0.0.0/0"
      egress.482069346.description:          ""
      egress.482069346.from_port:            "0"
      egress.482069346.ipv6_cidr_blocks.#:   "0"
      egress.482069346.prefix_list_ids.#:    "0"
      egress.482069346.protocol:             "-1"
      egress.482069346.security_groups.#:    "0"
      egress.482069346.self:                 "false"
      egress.482069346.to_port:              "0"
      ingress.#:                             "1"
      ingress.2541437006.cidr_blocks.#:      "1"
      ingress.2541437006.cidr_blocks.0:      "0.0.0.0/0"
      ingress.2541437006.description:        ""
      ingress.2541437006.from_port:          "22"
      ingress.2541437006.ipv6_cidr_blocks.#: "0"
      ingress.2541437006.protocol:           "tcp"
      ingress.2541437006.security_groups.#:  "0"
      ingress.2541437006.self:               "false"
      ingress.2541437006.to_port:            "22"
      name:                                  "ssh"
      owner_id:                              <computed>
      revoke_rules_on_delete:                "false"
      vpc_id:                                "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  + aws_subnet.main
      id:                                    <computed>
      assign_ipv6_address_on_creation:       "false"
      availability_zone:                     <computed>
      cidr_block:                            "10.0.1.0/24"
      ipv6_cidr_block:                       <computed>
      ipv6_cidr_block_association_id:        <computed>
      map_public_ip_on_launch:               "false"
      tags.%:                                "1"
      tags.Name:                             "Main"
      vpc_id:                                "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  + aws_vpc.main
      id:                                    <computed>
      assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block:      "false"
      cidr_block:                            "10.0.0.0/16"
      default_network_acl_id:                <computed>
      default_route_table_id:                <computed>
      default_security_group_id:             <computed>
      dhcp_options_id:                       <computed>
      enable_classiclink:                    <computed>
      enable_classiclink_dns_support:        <computed>
      enable_dns_hostnames:                  <computed>
      enable_dns_support:                    "true"
      instance_tenancy:                      <computed>
      ipv6_association_id:                   <computed>
      ipv6_cidr_block:                       <computed>
      main_route_table_id:                   <computed>


Plan: 6 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

I've read the docs but couldn't found any clue

Comment: You don't really need a separate EIP. Why not say `associate_public_ip_address = true` and output `aws_instance.proxy.public_ip_address`?

Comment: in my case, I really need :(

Comment: Ok, then where's your attach of EIP to the instance?

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/eip_association.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you lack EIP-to-instance association as described in https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/eip_association.html

```
resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  instance_id   = "${aws_instance.proxy.id}"
  allocation_id = "${aws_eip.pib.id}"
}
```

Ok, that wasn't it... Public routing then another possibility that I see is missing (In other words, route everything in that subnet towards IGW):

```
# Public routing
resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"    
}

resource "aws_route" "public_default" {
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.public.id}"
  gateway_id     = "${aws_internet_gateway.igw.id}"

  destination_cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public" {
  subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.main.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.public.id}"
}
```

And in your subnet definition you need:

```
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
```

Otherwise it will be a private subnet.

Comment: just did that, it linked to the instance correctly but i still can't shh

Comment: I manually created another IP and I just saw this new one has a public dns, while the terraformed one hasn't

Comment: Ow, wait, I just saw you're actually allocating EIP with instance linked to it. Hmm. Strange. Does it work if you allocate EIP by UI?

Comment: I used to do this process manually and always worked. Now I'm doing it through terraform and it doesn't